# Swagger UI and REST API on different servers

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have my services running in `kubernetes cluster` and `swagger UI` deployed in different K8 cluster. Now when I start the swagger UI application it tries to look for the APIs in the same cluster and gives `404`. I am using `swagger2`. How can tell swagger UI about the host for all the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

All paths are relative to the API server URL. The full request URL is constructed as /path. Global servers can also be overridden on the path level or operation level.

More:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

Please see this documentation for the correct kubernetes nodes and cluster addresses:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/